# MySQL database design for products with multiple properties and three types of properties

Tags: mysql, database-design, metadata

I need to build a database for products that have a set of generic properties such as name, price, size etc.. which I have done fine. But, each product has a set of nutritional values, which need to be put in a table as a separate design because a lot of products have unique properties that are not generic from product to product.

Not only do products have to have unique properties (that are sometimes shared between products), the properties have to be stored per 100g, per serving, and the %RDA values.

For example, one product has to show the potassium levels: per 100g = 702mg, per serving = 393mg, and %RDA = 20%.

```
                   per 100g      per 56g        %RDA
    Protien         71g           40g            -
    Potassium       702mg         393mg          20%
```

This is how the results ideally should be presented on each product page, bearing in mind each product will have up to about 20 properties, some could be unique and some used more than once.

I was thinking of having 2 tables:

```
Products Table: Product ID, Product name, Price

Product_meta Table: Pmeta_id, Product ID, metaKey, metaValue
```

But I was not sure how to store the values for per 100g, per serving and %RDA.

Also what would be a good way to query the DB to insert these values? Seems quite complicated with this much info per product..

Comment: You need a *unit* column in product meta which can have values such as Kilograms, grams, serving units, ML, %RDA, etc.

Comment: avoid EAV. use table inheritance. consider keeping measurements in a standardized form and calculating different values on the fly